# What's the best way in UNITY to communicate with server in real time sending and receiving string data

Tags: string, unity-game-engine, server, connection, real-time

I am starting an real time "word detecting" game and need a way to communicate with server in real time sending and receiving mostly string data maybe some int and bool too what is the best solution for this ? where should I start my R&D

Comment: Have you investigated websockets? its a real time transmission protocol over TCP, i use it for several projects https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/148975/websockets-server-for-unity3d

Comment: I think the question is just at the wrong place, should be addressed to https://serverfault.com/ perhaps.

Answer (score 2):

There are different types of networking solutions. You can have high level/low level apis for networking.

For low level apis you could look into LiteNetLib for unity and for high level apis you could check photon.

Here is a link comparing different networking solutions : [Solutions low/high level apis](https://www.gamedev.net/forums/topic/694718-benchmarknet-stress-test-for-enet-unet-litenetlib-lidgren-miniudp-hazel-photon-and-others/)

I would look into types of server aswell. P2p, authoritative server...

Comment: The answer is in the sense of the question and looks helpful. Nevertheless I'll propose the question for removal as it's not in the scope of Stack Overflow,